# how do I re-enable a JButton

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I have a program that tests numbers if they are prime.
I have a basic GUI that contains a textfield and a button called check. Now, I have extended this program by adding a simple GUI number keypad. On the original GUI, I added a new button called *keyboard* so when pressed, it will open the GUI number keypad and disable the check button. Now my question is how do I re-enable the check button if the GUI number keypad window has been closed?
Below is a snippet of my code:

```
        if (event.getSource()==jbKeyboard) {
            jbCheck.setEnabled(false);    
            KeyboardGui g = new KeyboardGui();
            if (g.equals(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)) {
                    jbCheck.setEnabled(true);
            }
         }
```

but this does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You add a `WindowListener` for the keypad, and in the `WindowClosing(WindowEvent e)` method, you can do your `jbCheck.setEnabled(true);`

Not sure what KeyboardGui, but something like this (added after you declare and initialize g):

```
g.addWindowListener(this);
```

Then you will need to `implement WindowListener` and add the appropriate methods.

Here is the Java Tutorial on window Listeners:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html

Comment: Thanks allot, and the keyboardgui is the keypad, sorry about that!

Comment: no no, I am just saying I am not sure what the code behind it is. I can see a few ways of doing the listener (that are dependent on how you implemented keypad), but I think once you read the java tutorial, you will be able to figure the rest out.

Comment: @BabatundeOmodayo: Youssef's solution is a good one (1+) to this answer, and for that, you should probably accept it. Another consideration is to display the number window in a modal dialog such as a JDialog. Then you don't even have to disable the check button in the first place because it won't be accessible until the modal dialog is no longer visible.